# Error creating a view in AWS Athena - Function uuid not registered

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena, trino

When creating a view definition in Athena which contains the uuid() function, an error is thrown saying that **"The function uuid is not registered"**.

Running the same SQL, including the uuid function, as a standalone query, works perfectly fine.

```
create or replace view my_db.vw_with_uuid as
    select uuid() as my_unique_id
;
```

I'm using DBeaver as a client (using the Simba Athena jdbc driver), but I'm getting the same error using the Athena Web Query Editor.

Anyone knows how to workaround this little issue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`uuid` function was added in [Trino (formerly Presto SQL) 312](https://trino.io/docs/current/release/release-312.html).

Athena is based on .172 or .217 (depending which athena version you use).